# How to make Wi-Fi file sharing in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I want to make Wi-Fi file sharing in my app, that UIViewController will have http address which user will can to write in desktop browser and user will can pass data to application over Wi-Fi. How can I make it? What are any libraries for it? I use Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7. Like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broad question, here as a broad answer.

You could try using the Multipeer Connectivity Framework that was introduced in iOS7.

This essentially wraps zero-configuration networking so you don't need to worry about IP addresses.

Comment: No, I didn't use this framework